# Answers with score of -3 or lower (on normal sites) and -8 or lower (on meta sites) are no longer greyed out after the series of redesigns

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, down-votes

Just look at [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-3+is%3Aa) on SO, [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-8+is%3Aa) on MSE, [this list](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-3+is%3Aa) on M&TV, [this list](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-3+is%3Aa) on UX, etc. In short all the sites which had a recent redesign or relatively recently graduated sites with those new SVGifyied designs...

Before all those redesigns, the answers with score of <-3 on normal (main) sites and answers with score of <-8 on metas (including MSE), were greyed out.

Was this feature removed intentionally?

Comment: Hopefully this means I will no longer need a userstylesheet to un-grey those posts.

Comment: [Jin says it's a bug which will be fixed.](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/site-design-update#comment4496_2374)

Comment: Update from Jin: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288436/2632129

Comment: @Jam Hey, didn't you see the comment? ;)

Comment: which comment? The MSO post has a link to here from Jin's comment (and my answer) and now a link from here to Jin's update there. So people on both MSO and MSE are updated one way or another

Comment: @Jam http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288183/why-arent-there-any-more-grayed-out-answers/288436#comment167768_288436

Comment: yes, that links to here, my link above is a link from here to there - so MSE users know about it being there (I know it caused an infinite loop, but unfortunate side affect to otherwise useful link).

Comment: @Jam Ok then :))